# How to show all output in Julia?

Tags: julia

Sometimes Julia will compact output using an ellipse to save space. For example, you can run `subtypes()` to see this.

A while back, I saw a Julia video where the person did something to show all output and the ellipse was not there in this case. Does anyone know how this is done?

Comment: assume that `a` is a big matrix, `print(a)` simply outputs all elements. Is that what you want?

Comment: for print all output exist `showall()`

Comment: @elsuizo: How do you use it? Say I want it to work on subtypes().

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/35551

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`showall()` no longer exists. It was remove in Julia v0.6. So the original answer to this question no longer exists. Now, you can use the following:

`show(IOContext(stdout, :limit=>false), subtypes(Any))`

Comment: Is there a way to get it to print in a vertical column rather than one big blob?

Comment: I don't think there is any dead simple way other than a loop or a map or something.. `for t in subtypes(Any) println(t) end`

Comment: as of 2019, this just gives `ERROR: UndefVarError: showall not defined`

Comment: I updated the answer with the best solution I could find. It is a community wiki, so feel free to update if you have a better answer, or this changes again in the future.

Comment: The answer of qwyh seems to do the trick.

Comment: (I'd changed my username from `qwyh` to `ymhan`; Daniel's comment is referring to my answer below)

Answer (score 6):

here's a shorter variant of that that should work:

`show(stdout, "text/plain", x)`

where x is the thing you want to print

Comment: Worked as expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On **DataFrames** you can use *allrows* and/or *allcols*:

```
using RDatasets

show(RDatasets.datasets(), allrows=true, allcols=true)
#763×5 DataFrame
# Row │ Package       Dataset                    Title                              Rows    #Columns 
#     │ String        String                     String                             Int64   #Int64   
#─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#   1 │ COUNT         affairs                    affairs                               601       18
#   2 │ COUNT         azdrg112                   azdrg112                             1798        4
#   3 │ COUNT         azpro                      azpro                                3589        6
#   4 │ COUNT         badhealth                  badhealth                            1127        3
#   5 │ COUNT         fasttrakg                  fasttrakg                              15        9
#...
```

Comment: Is there something similar for a simple matrix?

Comment: @becko Try `show(stdout, "text/plain", zeros(200,20))`

Answer (score 1):

For **IJulia** (Jupyter notebook) users:

`ENV["COLUMNS"] = 240`

Source: [DataFrames: display in a Jupyter notebook](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/dataframes-display-in-a-jupyter-notebook/24411)